# Is there a way to do command aliasing in matlab R2011b?

Tags: matlab

I am relatively new at Matlab. 
I am trying to create an alias for a command that looks like the following.

```
run('full/path/to/some/script').
```

In particular, I would like to be able to write something equivalent to Bash's

```
alias myAlias = run('full/path/to/some/script')
```

And then be able to type `myAlias` and get the same effect as the right hand side.

I have looked at the documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/alias.html), but I still get the error `Undefined function or variable 'alias'` when I try to use it, even after I first type `syms` at the prompt, so I believe that either I am not importing the toolbox correctly or this is not a feature in R2011b.

One additional requirement is that I would like the alias to stick even after I call `clear`, which should clear all the other active variables in the workspace.

Comment: `alias` from symbolic toolbox is not for this purpose.

Answer (score 3):

for example:

```
f = @() run('foldername\scriptname')
```

then just writing `f()` will execute `scriptname`.
 Here I've used an anonymous function, you can add more content to it if needed.

Comment: That is a horrible solution, avoid using `eval`. If you want an anonymous function, at least do `f = @() run('path/to/script')`. Also, the solution will not satisfy the requirement of not being removed by `clear`.

Comment: of course! just `run(...)` will do,  more elegant no doubt. I will edit my answer. But generally speaking why is `eval` a **horrible** solution?

Comment: In this case **horrible** is perhaps not the right wording as the command is a static string, i.e. it would be safe, but in general if you find yourself using `eval` in Matlab you are probably solving your problem the wrong way. SO has plenty of discussions regarding the use of `eval` please look them up if you are interested. For some Matlab fun, look at the output of `str2num('system(''dir'')')`

Answer (score 0):

You can make @natan's answer tolerate clearing the workspace by making it an m-file.
In `myAlias.m`, put `run('full/path/to/some/script')`. I'm sure you are aware of this solution, but you might not want to do so, because of the resulting messy file system.

You can simply add the m-file to some folder and use `addpath('where/ever/you/put/the/script')` to make it accessible.