# how to create a command alias in Matlab

Tags: matlab

Is there a similar concept to Unix 'alias' within Matlab?

This question [Is there a way to do command aliasing in matlab R2011b?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564592/is-there-a-way-to-do-command-aliasing-in-matlab-r2011b) suggests defining anonymous functions, and extending the answer these could be sourced at startup, but this results in the function handles appearing in the Workspace, which will disappear when cleared.

Is there a more robust and Unix analogous solution? Seems like a pretty useful thing to be able to do...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure why you would want to do this, but...

Assuming you are willing to have a directory on the path dedicated to aliases you can create m files in that directory to run the aliases. In this case the aliases will not exist in the workspace. You could of course just write the alias files your self, but the following function will create aliases for you automatically. The function can get confused if the function/script you are trying to alias is not currently on the search path. The function is not "perfect" in the sense that you do not write

```
alias myAlias = run('full/path/to/some/script')
```

but rather

```
alias myAlias full/path/to/some/script
```

---

```
function alias(aliasName, functionName)
% alias myfoo foo

    aliasPath = './alias';
    isscript = false;
    try
        nargin(functionName);
    catch %#ok<CTCH>
        isscript = true;
    end
    
    if isscript
        fileID = fopen([aliasPath, aliasName, '.m'],'w');
        fprintf(fileID, '%s\n', ['run(', functionName, ')']);
        fclose(fileID);
    else
        fileID = fopen([aliasPath, aliasName, '.m'],'w');
        fprintf(fileID, '%s\n', ['function varargout = ', aliasName, '(varargin)']);
        fprintf(fileID, '\t%s\n', ['varargout{1:nargout} = ', functionName, '(varargin{:});']);
        fprintf(fileID, '%s\n', 'end');
        fclose(fileID);
    end
end
```

Comment: you would want to do this so you can abbreviate long function calls and commands...or am i missing something as to why this would not be a good idea?

Comment: @user2846226 I could imagine wanting "aliases" but I am not sure why you need an automated way of creating them. It seems easier to just create a bunch of m-file aliases by hand.

Comment: i was more interested to find out IF there is support for this, seems the answer is no but thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. It's called a function. You just write a function to do whatever you want the alias to do. For example:

```
function cdhome
    cd(getenv('MATLABUSERPATH'))
```

Then just type `cdhome` at the command line, exactly like an alias in a unix shell. Note that `MATLABUSERPATH` is an environment variable I define in `startup.m`. It can be easier, just save a script called `cdhome.m` with the following content:

```
cd(getenv(<ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_THAT_DEFINES_MY_FAVORITE_PATH>))
```

Or how about:

```
clc; clear; close all;
```

Save that in a script file called `clean.m` and then simply put `clean` at the top of your scripts instead of `clc; clear; close all;`

No, it doesn't exactly follow the unix idea of having a bunch of alias's in a single configuration file that executes on startup.

But you can do that too. Put all your aliases in a switch block, in one function, call it `alias`:

```
    function alias(thecalledalias)
        switch thecalledalias
            case somealias
                % ... define some alias
            case someotheralias
                % ... define some other alias
         end
```

For autocomplete, which you would get with your shell, put a `functionSignatures.json` file in the same folder as the `alias.m` function file and populate it with your aliases:

```
{
   "_schemaVersion": "1.0.0",
   "alias":
   {
      "inputs":
      [
         {"name":"thecalledalias", "kind":"required", 
         "type":["char", "choices={'somealias','someotheralias'}"]}
      ]
  }
}
```

Then you will get autocomplete when you type `alias(...)` at the command line.

But to me it is easier to have one folder, call it `myaliases` with one script or function for each alias, and you get autocomplete at the command line just like when you call any function (i.e., no need to type `alias(<somealias>)`).

Comment: `clear` by itself clears all the variables from the workspace. `clear all` also removes function definitions and mex-files from memory. All this accomplished is decreasing performance. It should generally be avoided, according to the docs.

Comment: @CrisLuengo good call, thanks for the edits.